# Add class to body element based on viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

I am trying to add two classes to the body element using jQuery.

The first would take the URL and add it to the body element. The code I have truncates the class to the first 5 characters. However, I would like it to be the entire url (not including the extension) such that a file named `new_page.html` would add `class="new_page"`and `this-is-another-new_page.php` would add `class="this-is-another-new_page"`.

```
var newClass = window.location.href;
newClass = newClass.substring(newClass.lastIndexOf('/')+1, 5);
$('body').addClass(newClass);
```

The second class I would like to add is a detection of the viewport height that would add a class of `short` or `tall` based on the viewport height. In this case, I want to add a class that detects is the viewport height is less than `768` and adds the class `short` or `greater than or equal to 768` and add a class of `tall`.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `var newClass = window.location.pathname.split('.').shift()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check height using `$(window).height()`

```
$(function() {
    //taken from @Vohuman's comment
    var newClass = window.location.pathname.split('.').shift().slice(1);
    $('body').addClass(newClass);

    if($(window).height() < 768) {
       $("body").addClass("short");
    } else {
       $("body").addClass("tall");
    }
 })
```

Comment: That's almost perfect except it is adding a `/` before the file-name class as such `homepage-slideshow /index-fr short`. How do I not include the `/`?

Comment: Updated answer. Need to add `.slice(1)` for removing that `/`